# display html text in database occur error

Tags: html, mysql, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

I'm developing a web app using ExpressJS, MySQL, EJS.
I save data in database with HTML text.
Then, I get data from database and show into web, an error occur: HTML text show instead of plain text.

Output:

```
<p>Theo thông lệ, cứ mỗi lần xuân về chúng tôi lại tổ chức chuyến đi thăm hỏi và tặng quà cho những người nghèo, những người tàn tật. Lần này, khi được biết Trung tâm AD<a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=635416809813218&amp;set=pb.219378098083760.-2207520000.1378539213.&amp;type=3&amp;theater" target="_blank" title="học yoga">YOGA</a> tổ chức đợt quyên góp và tặng quà cho Trung tâm nuôi dưỡng người già cô đơn và trẻ em tàn tật huyện Ba Vì, tỉnh Sơn Tây, nhiều học viên và bạn bè của chúng tôi đã đăng ký tham gia. Từ nhiều ngày trước chuyến đi, chúng tôi đã tiếp nhận được các loại quà của các cá nhân, tổ chức gửi tặng. Càng gần đến ngày đi số lượng quà đóng góp càng tăng lên. Thậm chí tối muộn ngày 5/1/2008, một ngày trước chuyến đi có một số anh chị biết được tin về hoạt động từ thiện vẫn lặn lội mang quà đến đóng góp, như vợ chồng anh Hùng, Tiến địa chỉ tại 49 phố Hàng Chiếu, vợ chồng anh Quân chị Quỳnh tại 50 phố Yên Phụ.</p><p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://adyoga.com.vn/profiles/adyogacomvn/uploads/attach/thumbnail/1406716633_2.jpg" height="750" width="1000" border="0"></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Anh Phẩm, giám đốc Trung tâm nuôi dưỡng người già và trẻ em tàn tật khi được biết chúng tôi lên thăm và tặng quà cho Trung tâm thì rất mừng và cũng nhờ chúng&nbsp; tôi mua giúp 100 cái chiếu lớn nhỏ để cung cấp cho các cụ và các cháu trẻ nhỏ.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Việc tổ chức, phân loại quần áo, sách vở, đóng gói quà đã được chúng tôi hoàn tất từ chiều hôm trước chuyến đi. Đúng 7h30 ngày 6/1/2008 đoàn xe gồm 5 xe rời Trung tâm AD<a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=635416809813218&amp;set=pb.219378098083760.-2207520000.1378539213.&amp;type=3&amp;theater" target="_blank" title="học yoga">YOGA</a>
```

Can you help me solve this problem?
Thanks.

MySQL code:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `catalog` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

Comment: Is your page UTF-8? Try <meta charset="utf-8"> in your head tag

Comment: So if you do `SELECT * FROM articles` does it come out in proper Vietnamese? If so, your problem is not related to the database but the HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your database like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

Comment: Did you try @user3806613 solution as well? If so, post your db schema.

Answer (score 0):

you would also need this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and the PHP version:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

put the code above at the top of your php code before any other codes and view your php page in the browser. This will encode the html characters.